# What does The Doctor's Speech in The Rings of Akhaten refer to?

Tags: doctor-who

I recently watched the brilliant speech from The Rings of Akhaten again. For those who haven't seen it or don't remember it:

> I walked away from the last Great Time War. I marked the passing of
>   the Time Lords. I saw the birth of the universe and I watched as time
>   ran out, moment by moment, until nothing remained. No time. No space.
>   Just me. I walked in universes where the laws of physics were devised
>   by the mind of a mad man. I've watched universes freeze and creations
>   burn. I've seen things you wouldn't believe. I have lost things you
>   will never understand. And I know things. Secrets that must never be
>   told. Knowledge that must never be spoken. Knowledge that will make
>   parasite gods blaze. So come on, then. Take it! Take it all, baby!
>   Have it! You have it all!

Some of these I understand:

> I walked away from the last Great Time War.

Clear enough

> I marked the passing of the Time Lords.

Again makes sense, given he "killed" them.

> I saw the birth of the universe and I watched as time ran out, moment by moment, until nothing remained. No time. No space. Just me. I walked in universes where the laws of physics were devised by the mind of a mad man. I've watched universes freeze and creations burn.

I'm very vague on this put is some of it related to The Big Bang?

> I've seen things you wouldn't believe. I have lost things you will never understand. And I know things. Secrets that must never be told. Knowledge that must never be spoken. Knowledge that will make parasite gods blaze.

Possibly relating to the question which must never be answered, but at this point we've not been to Trenzalore so does he even know what knowledge is and why?

What do the unknown sections of these speech refer to?

Comment: "I've seen things you wouldn't believe," is a pretty clear reference to Blade Runner.

Comment: "I have lost things you will never understand", I don't think he's talking about material things. He lost lot of companions and loved them, maybe the "parasite God" is not able to understand human feelings

Answer (score 12):

You have to realize that The Doctor and his experiences are unique, even among other Time Lords. He has literally witnessed both the beginning and end of time itself, as well as the universe.  But we'll cover each part separately:

> I walked away from the last Great Time War. I marked the passing of
>   the Time Lords.

These two experiences are tied together. The Doctor was considered the only survivor of the [Great Time War](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Great_Time_War), a conflict which lasted 400 years in real-time, but spanned throughout the history of the universe. It saw the end of both the Daleks and the Time Lords as a power in the universe.

> I saw the birth of the universe and I watched as time ran out, moment
>   by moment, until nothing remained. No time. No space. Just me.

These two lines mean what they say. The 4th Doctor implied that he had witnessed the birth of the universe itself in "[Destiny of the Daleks](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny_of_the_Daleks)". He later witnessed the end of the universe during his 10th incarnation, although technically (in his 11th incarnation) he actually *caused* it before resetting the universe back to its proper state in "[The Big Bang](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Big_Bang)".

> I walked in universes where the laws of physics were devised by the
>   mind of a mad man.

This is most likely a reference to the anti-matter universe controlled by [Omega](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Omega).

> I've watched universes freeze and creations burn. I've seen things you
>   wouldn't believe. I have lost things you will never understand.

These lines could refer to numerous different things. The "universes freeze" bit could even be a reference to Gallifrey itself, which was frozen in time.

> And I know things. Secrets that must never be told. Knowledge that must never be spoken.

Again, this could be a reference to any number of things. Several Doctor Who stories have revolved around the concept of secrets - including the [true name](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Question) of the Doctor himself, a secret that had the potential to destroy reality itself.

> Knowledge that will make parasite gods blaze.

This last bit is probably referring to The Doctor's understanding of causality and the infinite possibilities of not only the universe itself, but also the human race. Clara granted this understanding to [Akhaten](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Akhaten) (a "parasite god") and it destroyed him.

Answer (score 3):

As a partial answer to some of the lines:

> I saw the birth of the universe

Possibly referring to the events of *Castrovalva* where the TARDIS travels back to "Event One" -- the Big Bang.

> I watched as time ran out, moment by moment, until nothing remained.

Could be, as you suspected, *The Big Bang* where the Doctor watched the universe end.

> I walked in universes where the laws of physics were devised by the mind of a mad man.

Almost certainly a reference to the antimatter universe created by the mad Omega in *The Three Doctors*.

Answer (score 1):

> I walked in universes where the laws of physics were devised by the mind of a mad man.

This may indeed refer to Omega and the anti-matter universe he inhabited in *The Three Doctors*, but there are other possibilities -- especially considering that Omega's physical form had faded away to nothing without him realizing it, which tells us he didn't really control the Universe as much as he thought.

There are two earlier stories that potentially fit the bill:

*The Celestial Toymaker* (1st Doctor)

The Doctor and companions are trapped in a domain controlled by a godlike ("Q"-like?) being who forces them to participate in games of his devising.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Celestial_Toymaker

*The Mind Robber* (2nd Doctor)

The TARDIS is forced to exit time and space to evade disaster, and the crew find themselves in a white void controlled by The Master (no, not that Master, a different one), who is getting old and needs somebody to take his place as the controller of this realm.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mind_Robber

Answer (score 0):

"I have lost things that you will never understand," I believe that he might also be referring to the loss of his children and home planet, because obviously the "parasite god" can't feel the loss of children or a home, it is just a huge ball of gas.

Comment: This feels like a guess. Can you offer any confirmation that this is what the writers had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

"I've lost things you would never understand" might be referring to all the companions that have died and all the people that died in his name.

Comment: This feels like a guess. Can you offer any confirmation that this is what the writers had in mind?